# Wrong colors in of Telescope window

Tags: neovim, plugin-telescope

Upon upgrading to version 8.0 in neovim, Telescope's window now has purple colors in the background. In v7.2 the background color was that of Normal.

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug introduced by [PR neovim#13457](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/pull/13457). Whether it's a bug in neovim or in Telescope is unknown. The bug is being tracked in [this issue](https://github.com/nvim-telescope/telescope.nvim/issues/2145). Hopefully it will get fixed soon.

In the meantime, you can link NormalFloat highlight group (see `:h hl-NormalFloat`) to Normal (see `:h hl-Normal`) to revert to original behaviour.

```
hi! link NormalFloat Normal
```

NOTE that this will make *all* floating windows (using NormalFloat highlight group) transparent, so be aware of that.